# How to find open port on specific IP address in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, networking, port, netstat, print-server

At work, we connected print-server to a printer via USB, to make a printer network-available.

Setting-up as network printer was successful, but at work, additionally we need to specify a port number.

Scanning using `netstat` lists hardware available in LAN, but it doesn't pick IP address of print-server, although I'm able to ping it.

Is it possible to scan for open port for a specific IP address, let's say `xx.xx.xx.xx` using `netstat` or any other tools?

[image]

Comment: What system at your work is requiring the port?

Comment: @music2myear Hi! In-house developed software requires port of a printer. It seems print-server that supports jetdirect has port 9100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program `netstat` is for displaying open and connected ports and sockets on local machine. To scan and get open ports on remote machine you can use `nmap`. The command is something like:

```
nmap <IP of print server>
```

But before this you can check these ports: 2501, 5001, 9100, 9101, 9102, and 9600 which are usually used from print server.
If you want to scan for all ports (more than 1000 by default) you should use command:

```
nmap -p- <IP of print server>
```